# How do I grant a service user sufficient rights to create registry keys in windows 7

Tags: windows-services, uac, registry, perfmon

I have an application that runs as a service, and dynamically creates and publishes windows performance (perfmon) counters.

When I run the application under my own account (as a service) which has administrative privileges, I get the following error:
714: The specified registry key is referenced by a predefined handle.

When I run the application from the command line, no error is produced.

I believe that this is a result of UAC, but I don't particularly want to disable UAC altogether.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have a similar problem. A service seems not to be able to read the registry on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough just to be logged in as an administrator. The service needs to have an [embedded manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715209/write-access-to-program-files-folder/1885543#1885543) that sets the requestedExecutionLevel to requireAdministrator.