# Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\~\TextFiles\ActiveUsers.txt'

Tags: c#

I tried many ways to access a text file in my Visual Studio 2012 Solution from a folder named `TextFiles`

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"~/TextFiles/ActiveUsers.txt", true))
{
    file.WriteLine(model.UserName.ToString());
}
```

But it kept on throwing the error

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS
>   Express\~\TextFiles\ActiveUsers.txt'.

Not sure where I made a mistake

Comment: Are you sure there is a path called C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\~\ ?

Comment: @SonerGönül C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\ Exists but not after that.. I am trying to access a file in my solution which is stored in a folder

Comment: It is clearly you writing wrong path. Where is your file exactly in your solution? Right click it and see it properties or right click it and go _open containing folder_.

Comment: Yeah but I don't want give the absolute path .. actual location is C:\ABCWorking\ABC - Candian Version\WhiteBoardApp\TextFiles\ActiveUsers.txt

Comment: What `~` stands for? Do you think it's current directory? =D

Comment: I thought it refers to the current solution

Comment: From [`StreamWriter Constructor (String, Boolean)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) **path: The complete file path to write to**.

Comment: @Dev: Almost. It points to the folder in which your application is running. E.g. if you are running an .exe in your solution's Debug folder, `~` will equal your Debug folder. If you put the .exe on your Desktop, `~` will equal your Desktop folder. I see no overlap between the application location and your target file location (apart from it being on the same C drive). I doubt if relative paths are actually relevant in this scenario.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use [`HttpServerUtility.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) which will turn the `~/` portion of the path in to the real location it resildes on your hard drive.

So that would change your code to (assuming you are in one of the IIS classes that expose a `Server` property to it's methods)

```
var path = Server.MapPath(@"~/TextFiles/ActiveUsers.txt");

using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path, true))
{
    file.WriteLine(model.UserName.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I ran into a similar issue and ended up using

```
string sFileName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/dirname/readme.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I just ran into this problem myself and wanted to add what I've just discovered, in case it's helpful to anyone else.

If you have UAC turned off but are not running with elevated permissions, and try to write to restricted files (e.g. the "Program Files" folder) you'll get the "could not find a part of the path" error, instead of the (correct) access denied error.

To eliminate the problem, run with elevated permissions as in this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1885543/3838199

Answer (score 0):

`~` is not the "user home" or anything else in Windows. You can still set the path as relative to the working directory (where the executable is) by just not specifying a full path.

Answer (score 0):

For .netcore 3.x
You should make use of `IWebHostEnvironment` using dependency injection.
You can then use it in your code this way

```
string wwwRootPath = _hostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
string path = Path.Combine(wwwRootPath, $"TextFiles{Path.PathSeparator}ActiveUsers.txt");
```

Ensure to use `PathSeparator` otherwise you might face the same error due to the variance in your hosting environment.