# How to save a text file in special path

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make and save text file in special path but it was not working.

```
StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\\Users\\log.txt");
        file.Write("Hi macho");
        file.Close();
```

If I write it this way it save on project Projects\log\log\bin\Debug

```
StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("log.txt");
        file.Write("Hi macho");
        file.Close();
```

[image]

Comment: What error message is shown? I would GUESS that it is a permission error that is shown?

Comment: @Thomas check the picture

Comment: Yup it is an authorization error @Thomas. Would have added the pic to the post but there is already a pending edit

Comment: Try to run the program as admin and see if it is still not working.

Comment: Why are you saving to the root of **Users**? Normal permissions won't allow that.  Instead try, `@"c:\Users\Miss Piggy\somefolder"` - assuming Miss Piggy is currently logged in

Answer (score 4):

As the error message shows you have no permission to write into this folder.

If we take windows into account you normally don't write into C:\users but into c:\users\yourUserName\Documents ,.... .

If you really want to write into a protected folder you need administration rights thus an option would be to tell the system you are in as administrator. This is possible via impersonation:

```
using (new Impersonation(domain, username, password))
{
    // do the file access
}
```

Although this can open pandoras box tbh and should be avoided thus I would strongly suggest that you write only into folders that exist for that very purpose.

Furthermore it can be with some operating systems that the above method won't work (UAC for the go there). Then you would either have to run the application as administrator instead or embed a administration privileges regquest into the applications manifest, ....

A bit more on this in a different stackoverflow post:
[Write Access to Program Files folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715209/write-access-to-program-files-folder)

Edit:
*One little detail on this in addition. If your program is located in the program files folder and you want to log into the same folder as your program resides in, you will face the same problem still.
Thus for example you have your programn located in c:\program files\myProgram you can't log into this without special permissions (aka admin rights normally).*

Comment: As a comment here (not part of the answer). When I stumbled upon the can't write into my own programs folder problem myself I really found that windows behaviour counter intuitive (I get it that one can't write into c:\program files without admin permissions, but in your own subfolder I would have expected it to work, which it does not you still need admin permissions there).

Answer (score 0):

You can save text file in a special path where you have access rights. There, you can pass it through the streamwriter method.

```
StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\log.txt");
        file.Write("Hi macho");
        file.Close();
```

Comment: the error message is "Access to tha path  C:\log.txt is denied"                              
            try
            {
                StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\log.txt");
                file.Write("Hi macho");
                file.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception er)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(er.Message);
            }

Comment: have you tried adding a new text document to that location(local C)? It must be the access rights.

Comment: The problem is that c:\log is writing to c:\    c:\, c:\program files, c:\users (without the username and the subfolder to write to)  are all protected

Comment: @Juran c:\ itself is protected under the most recent windows.  he would have to create a subfolder like c:\logs and write into that one

Comment: alright. @anushkachathuranga, in order for you to be able to write a text file, you must have access rights to a certain folder/subfolder

Comment: then i tried to save file in another path like drive F: it saved.it not allowed to save the file in drive C: at nowhere

Comment: @anushkachathuranga That is normal. You have the problem under windows that certain folders are seen as critical in terms of security. Thus you need admin rights in order to write to them (as I stated in my answer even impersonation does not work for these under the newest windows you really need to run the applicaiton with admin rights). these are c:\, c:\program files, c:\windows (as far as I'm aware), c:\users (without the subfolders for specific users), .... That is because the OS is located on c:\.

Comment: so you must then change the parameter of streamwriter to drive f. I'm afraid that's your only destination to save for now, unless you login as admin.

Comment: or run the program as admin. Reminds me of one little detail on that problem I will put that into my answer (you will have problems even logging into your programs folder if it is located in program files)